# Unhandled Promise rejection when handling firebase reauthentication

Tags: firebase, react-native, asynchronous, promise

I'm getting a "potentially unhandled promise rejection". It's caused by the updateEmail function when I input an invalid email. But then the setSuccess function is being called. Shouldn't it wait for the updateEmail and then skip straight to the catch block when the email is invalid?

```
const reAuthenticate = (currentPassword) => {
        const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(
            auth.currentUser.email,
            currentPassword
        );
        return reauthenticateWithCredential(auth.currentUser, credential);
    };
    const onEmailUpdate = (currentPassword, newEmail) => {
        reAuthenticate(currentPassword)
            .then(() => {
                const user = auth.currentUser;
                updateEmail(user, newEmail);
            })
            .then(() => {
                setSuccess(
                    "Email Updated! However this might take some time to take effect."
                );
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log(e);
                setError(formatErrorMsg(e))
            });
    };
```

I assume it's not propagating properly, but I don't understand why?
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Assuming `updateEmail` function returns a promise, change `updateEmail(user, newEmail);` to `return updateEmail(user, newEmail);`. This will ensure that the promise of the `then` method waits for the promise returned by the `updateEmail` function to settle. It will also ensure that the rejection of `updateEmail` promise is caught.

Comment: Thats the one! Thank you